# C# How do i change a label text from another form

Tags: c#, forms, text

So i have 2 forms.

Form 1 is my main form, and form 2 is where I enter text in a textbox to be displayed on a label on form 1. Also the button to 'confirm' and actually change the entered text of my label is on form 2 which needs to stay that way.

for some reason this does not work.

Form 2 has a text-box and a button, when I press the button, it changes the string value of the designated string. 
This string is linked to a label on form 1. the string is being changed so that is not the problem I confirmed this by a adding a button which pops up a message box showing the new string value.

While searching for an answer I found that is must be some sort of refreshing problem, I tried a lot of methods with no success. Only methods that did work where those who would put my button onto form 1 instead of 2.

I've been googling for 3 hours straight on how to fix this problem but either the methods don't work or they change my button from form 2 to my main form (form 1).

Please don't call me lazy I really can't find a method that works!

EDIT:

Code

```
GameScreen.cs

namespace _2pGame
{   
    public partial class GameScreen : Form
    {     
        public  GameScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            P1NameLabel.Text = gm.P1Name;
            P1ClassLabel.Text = gm.P1Class;
            P2NameLabel.Text = gm.P2Name;
            P2ClassLabel.Text = gm.P2Class;                
        }       

        private void PlayerInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayerInfo playerinfoload = new PlayerInfo();
            playerinfoload.Show();
        }
   }
```

}

PlayerInfo.cs

```
namespace _2pGame 
{       
    public partial class PlayerInfo : Form 
    { 
        public PlayerInfo() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        public void ConfirmPlayerInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gm.P1Class = P1ClassChoice.Text;
            gm.P1Name = P1TextBox.Text;
            gm.P2Class = P2ClassChoice.Text;
            gm.P2Name = P2TextBox.Text;                     
        }   
    }
}
```

Refs.cs

```
namespace _2pGame
{    
    public partial class gm
    {        
        public static string 
        P1Class,
        P2Class,
        P1Name,
        P2Name;        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really post your actual code (or a redacted one if it is too long) that shows this incorrect behavior

Comment: there is most likely something wrong with how you link your string to the label on form 1. just because your string changes does not mean that it will also change the label. we need to see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach to this very well know situation is through delegates....

In your PlayerInfo form declare

```
public partial class PlayerInfo : Form 
{ 
    // define the delegate type (a parameterless method that returns nothing)
    public delegate void OnConfirmPlayer();

    // declare a public variable of that delegate type
    public OnConfirmPlayer PlayerConfirmed;

    .....

    public void ConfirmPlayerInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gm.P1Class = P1ClassChoice.Text;
        gm.P1Name = P1TextBox.Text;
        gm.P2Class = P2ClassChoice.Text;
        gm.P2Name = P2TextBox.Text;

        // Check is someone is interested to be informed of this change
        // If someone assign a value to the public delegate variable then
        // you have to call that method to let the subscriber know 
        if (PlayerConfirmed != null) 
            PlayerConfirmed();
    }
}
```

Then in your GameScreen form, just before showing the PlayerInfo form, set the public `PlayerInfo.PlayerConfirmed` to a method into the GameScreen form class

```
private void PlayerInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlayerInfo playerinfoload = new PlayerInfo();

    // Subscribe to the notification from PlayerInfo instance
    playerinfoload.PlayerConfirmed += PlayerHasBeenConfirmed;

    playerinfoload.Show();
}

// Method that receives the notification from PlayerInfo 
private void PlayerHasBeenConfirmed()
{
     P1NameLabel.Text = gm.P1Name;
     P1ClassLabel.Text = gm.P1Class;
     P2NameLabel.Text = gm.P2Name;
     P2ClassLabel.Text = gm.P2Class; 
}
```

This approach has the advantage to avoid a coupling between the GameScreen and the PlayerInfo. No need to know inside the PlayerInfo the existance of a GameScreen form and the name of its properties. You just publish a delegate that a subscriber could register to be informed of the changes and let the subscriber acts on its own code.

Comment: Thanks this works! i'll be using this although i dont fully understand it. but that will come after some research!

Comment: The keyword _delegate_ allows us to define a type in the same way as when you use the keyword _class_. This kind of type is used to define variables, again, like you do with classes. Instead of properties and methods, this type consists in a reference to a method. Once you have a delegate type you could declare variables of this type and assign values to them with the notation _delegate variable += functioname_. At this point you could use the variable to call the method. [delegates C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

Comment: There is something else to be said about threads and thread safety that is not guaranteed with only this code but this is probably out of context for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to your main form and assign the textbox values each time they need to be updated.

```
public partial class PlayerInfo : Form 
{ 
    private readonly GameScreen _main;

    public PlayerInfo(GameScreen main) 
    {
        _main = main;
        InitializeComponent();        
     }

    public void ConfirmPlayerInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gm.P1Class = P1ClassChoice.Text;
        gm.P1Name = P1TextBox.Text;
        gm.P2Class = P2ClassChoice.Text;
        gm.P2Name = P2TextBox.Text;

        main.P1NameLabel.Text = gm.P1Name;
        main.P1ClassLabel.Text = gm.P1Class;
        main.P2NameLabel.Text = gm.P2Name;
        main.P2ClassLabel.Text = gm.P2Class;  

    }
}
```

You also need to pass the reference when the PlayerInfo form is created

```
private void PlayerInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerInfo playerinfoload = new PlayerInfo(this); //pass ref to self
        playerinfoload.Show();
    }
```

Note that there are other better ways to do this, but this is the easiest that I can think of.
You can probably look at events or Mediator pattern if you want something better.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, method works. but seen the potential of steve's code i'll be using his.

Comment: Yup, Steve's code is definitely the better approach