# Retrieving data from MS Access and display it to label in another form

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have this code in my `btnLogin` in `Form1` to get data from `MS Access database` and I want it to display in `Form2`using label but I don't know how to pass it to `Form2`

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        if ((this.txtUser.Text == "admin") && (this.txtPass.Text == "admin"))
        {
            Form1 main = new Form1();
            main.txtHere.Text = txtUser.Text;
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else {
            command.CommandText = "select * from StudentsTBL where LastName='" + txtUser.Text + "' and FirstName='" + txtPass.Text + "'";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.Read()) {
                count = count + 1;
                //count++;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                List<String> stdNo = new List<String>();
                List<String> middleName = new List<String>();
                List<String> section = new List<String>();
                List<String> year = new List<String>();
                List<String> sem = new List<String>();
                List<String> address = new List<String>();
                List<String> dob = new List<String>();
                List<String> gender = new List<String>();
                List<String> age = new List<String>();
                List<String> contact = new List<String>();
                List<String> desc = new List<String>();

                command = new OleDbCommand("select * from StudentsTBL", connection);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    stdNo.Add(reader["StudentNo"].ToString());
                    middleName.Add(reader["Middle"].ToString());
                    section.Add(reader["stdSection"].ToString());
                    year.Add(reader["stdYear"].ToString());
                    sem.Add(reader["stdSem"].ToString());
                    address.Add(reader["stdAddress"].ToString());
                    dob.Add(reader["stdDob"].ToString());
                    gender.Add(reader["stdGender"].ToString());
                    age.Add(reader["stdAge"].ToString());
                    contact.Add(reader["ContactNo"].ToString());
                    desc.Add(reader["stdDesc"].ToString());
                }
                StudentProfile stdProfile = new StudentProfile(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
                stdProfile.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password!!");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

source: [Getting data from MS Access database and display it in a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128361/getting-data-from-ms-access-database-and-display-it-in-a-listbox)

Comment: Um, what `Form2`?  What's the name of your `Label` field?

Comment: I want to display the data to `form2`

Comment: [Forms are just classes](http://www.contrivedexample.com/ce/post/2015/02/15/forms-are-just-classes.aspx)

Comment: If you are trying to get Form1 talk to Form2, you can use delegates or constructor injection. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179975/1862333

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not using structures ?
It will make your like easy yo can handle a lot of information in a single
variable.

And why you not make a global variable ?
It will be available from any part of you application.

I have project like this on [GitHub](https://github.com/MrAlex6204/DotNetAndMsAccessExample) you can downloaded as example reference

```
    structure UserInfo{
  public string stdNo;
  public string middleName;
  public string section;
  public string year;
  public string sem;
  public string address;
  public string dob;
  public string gender;
  public string age;
  public string contact;
  public string desc;
}

//===>Define a global variable to handle
public static UserInfo LoggedUsrInfo  = new UserInfo();

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        if ((this.txtUser.Text == "admin") && (this.txtPass.Text == "admin"))
        {
            Form1 main = new Form1();
            main.txtHere.Text = txtUser.Text;
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else {
            command.CommandText = "select * from StudentsTBL where LastName='" + txtUser.Text + "' and FirstName='" + txtPass.Text + "'";
            DataTable Tbl = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Tbl.Load(reader,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);//===>Retrieve data and load to datatble
            reader.Close();//Close the reader
            if (Tbl.Rows.Count > 0) {//Count if the data table retrieve some info
                DataTable TblInfo = new DataTable();
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");


                command = new OleDbCommand("select * from StudentsTBL", connection);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                TblInfo.Load(reader,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
                reader.Close();//Close the reader
                    LoggedUsrInfo.stdNo = TblInfo.Rows[0]["StudentNo"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.middleName = TblInfo.Rows[0]["Middle"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.section = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdSection"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.year = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdYear"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.sem =TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdSem"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.address = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdAddress"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.dob = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdDob"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.gender = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdGender"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.age = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdAge"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.contact = TblInfo.Rows[0]["ContactNo"].ToString();
                    LoggedUsrInfo.desc = TblInfo.Rows[0]["stdDesc"].ToString();

                StudentProfile stdProfile = new StudentProfile(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
                stdProfile.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password!!");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }


/*
you can access to UserInfo calling in this way from your Form2
Load Event

Label1.Text = Form1.LoggedUsrInfo.middleName;

*/
```